# Problema con una importación en flutter

Tags: flutter

Llevo mucho tiempo intentando solucionar esto:

[image: Problema de mi código]

Problema:

> _CastError (type 'Time' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' in type cast).

He intentado todas las opciones que me da el SDK de Flutter. El cual está actualizado a la última versión.

Comment: Por favor, pon tanto en el título como en el cuerpo de la pregunta _cuál es el error_. No todos pueden visualizar las imágenes. Lee [ask].

Comment: por favor el problema sigue sucediendo y no encuentro solución...

[GitHub](https://github.com/0w4n/HubApp/blob/main/lib/main.dart#:~:text=DateTime%20today%20%3D%20Tiempo()%3B)

Comment: "He intentado todas las opciones" no es una buena descripción. Ahí es claro en el mensaje que te está diciendo `Estoy intentando hacer el cast que me pides de Time() a DateTIme pero no puedo hacerlo implícito porque no son clases relacionables`. Significa que eso que intentaste debería incluir alguna forma de cast explícito, transformando la hora en Time a una fecha hora. tl;dr: ¿¿¿Qué se supone que debe poner la máquina en tiempo de ejecución en la "parte de fecha" del DateTIme????

Answer (score 0):

Estás utilizando un `DateTime` y el error te dice que falla porque se intenta hacer un castin de `Time` a `DateTime`. Deberías utilizar un `Time` para esto. Por ejemplo:

```
late Time today = Time();
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente lo que hace el código: lee [answer].